# Альтернатива капче

Tags: php, captcha

Доброго времени суток! Такой вопрос - если я вместо капчи буду проверять поле user-agent массива server, будет ли это достаточной защитой от ботов?

Comment: конечно нет.

Comment: определенно нет, если кто-то задастся идеей получить данные с вашего сайта или к примеру отправить туда какую-то информацию то он даже js-ы пропарсит и картинки сравнит, выберет методы которыми сможет безпрепятсвенно отправить или получить информацию с сайта. Другое дело если ваш сайт достаточно бесполезен то никто заниматься такими глупостями не станет. По моему пока ничего лучше чем капча точнее reCaptcha не придумали.

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Если кто-то задастся целью написать бота для вашего сайта, то сможет сравнить хедеры, посылаемые ботом и браузером, понять, что при наличии user-agent'а запрос проходит, и вставить его в хедер запроса от бота.